# ne59j7630ss Samsung range burning hot

Tags: appliances

Front of range top gets extremely hot when using oven. Oven door gasket has already been replaced.

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Home Improvement. Sounds like the oven is faulty, but I'm not sure what else we could say. And, you should probably [take our tour](//diy.stackexchange.com/tour) so you'll know how best to participate here.

Comment: There should be an inner and outer front door with insulation between. Unscrew the "clam-shell" door and include a picture of the interior.